# power bi embedded "hide toolbar paginated report"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to embed Power BI Reports(User Owns Data)
could you please help me how to hide tool bar for paginated report in power bi embedded
?
what is the setting to hide the tool bar

```
var config = {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl ,
    id: embedReportId,
    permissions: models.Permissions.All,
    settings: {
        bars: {
            actionBar: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        filterPaneEnabled: false,
        navContentPaneEnabled: false
    },

};
```

Comment: Did you tried what's [written in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#panes)?

Comment: I tried it nope doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

The paginated report does not support hiding toolbar. It only supports enable/disable and expand/collapse of parameters pane.

For more details on paginated report embed capabilities please refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-paginated-report